# How to Limit Total Number of Items in Cart

Tags: cart, shopping-cart, quantity

Been looking for something in this regard for a while, but have not been able to find a solution with a clean implementation guide. I just need to be able to limit the total number of items in the shopping cart - for example, a maximum of 7 total items, anything greater would throw an error message to the user (or something along those lines).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

P.S. - I'm a relative beginner when it comes to modifying Magento code on the back-end, so please do not be put off by what may seem to be a stupid question in response to any suggestions.

Comment: Please refer [this link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/452/how-can-i-limit-products-that-can-be-bought-added-to-cart). Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

I am not too much experienced person to give answer but i think you should go to system->configuration->catalog->inventory->Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart and limit the no of products

Comment: Andrew, this limit applies to cart item, not the whole cart. I think he is looking for solution to limit items in the whole cart.

Comment: ohh yes @WojtekNaruniec Then i think he might need to override some code. By admin panel he will not get answer.